# How do i get the data of the paths and shapes of an <image> tag within an svg

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, svg

I am having problems with the displaying of my image with as a source an URL, the problem is that is will not show within my svg `<mask>` when used as a `<image x="0" y="0" height="350" width="350" attr.xlink:href="URL">` I know this must work because when i place the tag anywhere else in the svg it does show, but because i want it within the `<mask>` i need to find a way to succeed. when i open the image in a notepad file and copy the data into the `<mask>` tag it works perfectly, but because i need the `<image>` to change when the url changes i cannot hard code it into the `<mask>`

therefore the solution i thought of was to convert the `<image>` to a string to obtain the data and put this into a variable which i can place inside the mask. But i cannot find anywhere how i should convert this if it is even possible.
i want to convert this element of my html page

`<svg xmlns:attr.xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/xlink">
      <image height="350" width="350" attr.xlink:href="URL"></image>
 </svg>`

into this to put it in a variable:

```
<polygon  points="135.956,125.591 137.161,130.401 142.109,130.061 137.906,132.693 139.759,137.294 135.956,134.111 132.153,137.294 134.006,132.693 129.803,130.061 134.751,130.401 "/>

<polygon  points="205.763,125.24 206.968,130.05 211.915,129.71 207.713,132.343 209.566,136.943 205.763,133.76 201.96,136.943 203.812,132.343 199.61,129.71 204.557,130.05 "/>
<g>
    <g>
        <path  d="M155.837,153.597c0,0,0.126-0.008,0.362-0.022c0.236-0.012,0.582-0.034,1.024-0.034 c0.441-0.003,0.979,0.018,1.591,0.059c0.611,0.037,1.298,0.045,2.05,0.025c0.752-0.022,1.565-0.062,2.42-0.161 c0.852-0.111,1.778-0.246,2.727-0.261c0.948-0.025,1.931-0.039,2.93,0.068c 0.498,0.049,0.989,0.105,1.484,0.129 c0.494,0.027,0.996,0.034,1.493,0.032c1.008,0.01,1.986-0.048,2.979-0.162c0.998-0.109,1.985-0.093,2.929-0.069 c0.477,0.017,0.943,0.039,1.401,0.092c0.453,0.058,0.896,0.114,1.327,0.168c0.854,0.099,1.667,0.138,2.42,0.161 c0.751,0.02,1.439,0.011,2.05-0.025c0.612-0.041,1.15-0.063,1.591-0.059c0.441,0,0.788,0.022,1.024,0.034 c0.236,0.014,0.362,0.022,0.362,0.022s-0.504,0.028-1.381,0.124 c-0.439,0.045-0.967,0.131-1.579,0.225 c-0.612,0.095-1.307,0.17-2.065,0.199c-0.756,0.035-1.579,0.056-2.451-0.006c-0.872-0.067-1.767-0.145-2.703-0.138 c-0.941-0.001-1.905,0.037-2.883,0.144c-0.981,0.124-2.014,0.198-3.018,0.195c-0.509-0.004-1.014-0.016-1.521-0.049 c-0.506-0.03-1.011-0.093-1.501-0.147c-0.977-0.108-1.944-0.145-2.882-0.144 c-0.939-0.006-1.832,0.069-2.704,0.138 c-0.872,0.062-1.695,0.04-2.451,0.006c-0.757-0.029-1.453-0.104-2.064-0.199c-0.611-0.093-1.14-0.179-1.579-0.224 C156.341,153.625,155.837,153.597,155.837,153.597z"/>
    </g>
</g>
```

is there a way to do this in javascript/typescript? or should i try some other way. i am using angular in this project

**EDIT**

i am trying it this way because i do not know what to do to fix my problem in my angular application.

i am trying to show designs on productimage for a webshop, the designs consists of text elements, which the users can adjust, and most of the time a svg logo of some sorts. because the designs mostly consists out of different colors, i am working with masking to make sure the correct design is shown. The problem is that the logo is not showing but the text is and when i paste the raw data into the mask it is working only with a  tag within the mask it is not. therefore i am trying to obtain the raw data out of the image tag which i now have hidden on the top of my html page

Comment: It's hard to tell, what you are actually trying to solve. As a hint: to access attributes with a namespace in JavaScript, specialized methods exist; for example [`Element.getAttributeNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNS). Using such namespacedd methods, you can alter the `xlink:href` to load another image.

Comment: I have the `<image>` tag hidden on my page, and now i am trying through document.getElementById() to get to the raw data such as the polygon and the paths, when i have this data i will then put it in a variable to put into my mask, this will then solve my problem, i just dont know how i get the raw data out of the element

Comment: This is still a description of your current (and possibly flawed) approach to whatever. It is often wise to tell something about the original problem that you are going to solve, not what attempt you've tried to solve that problem. Why is the `image` hidden? Why is there a requirement to copy and translate polygon data at all?

Comment: i edited my question to show why i need to copy and translate the data, hopefully now it is more clear what i am trying to do

Comment: The DOM of an <image> element is inaccessible

Comment: this means that the thing i am trying to achieve is impossible?

Comment: You could replace <image> with an <iframe> or <object> tag, maybe. Alternatively you could just have the SVG inline in your html page.